# Can't set up Slack App Auth/Scope for distrobution

Tags: json, slack-api

I'm trying to figure out how to set up the **auth flow to distribute** my Slack app. I currently have it installed for my team and currently I'm able to run some json in my terminal and it spits out the formatted post I'm looking for great. So I don't have any files, I just copy and paste the json into the terminal and manually change the text for each story. It's simply a POST method.

Ideally I'd like to be able to do that and anyone who has my app installed sees the posts I send through my terminal. Does anyone know how to set up the auth/scope?

Comment: If you are in to PHP here is an example for an install script. https://github.com/ErikKalkoken/slackapp

Comment: Other than that please read the official documentation. Its explains it pretty well: https://api.slack.com/docs/oauth